# Install php53 on CentOS 5.10 without httpd dependency

Tags: centos, httpd, centos5, php5, dependencies

I would like to install php53 on CentOS 5.10 64-bit without the httpd dependency. The reason being the production server has a custom compiled binary of a newer version of httpd.

Is installing php53 on CentOS5 without the httpd dependency even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the workaround that I did:

#### Install `yum-utils` and find out what files are in the package `php53`

```
# yum install yum-utils
# repoquery --list php53
/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf
/usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
/var/lib/php/session
/var/www/icons/php.gif
```

#### Install the `yum-downloadonly` plugin for `yum`

```
# yum install yum-downloadonly
```

#### Download the `php53` RPM package without installing

```
# yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=/home/dump php53
```

#### Unpack the RPM package

```
# rpm2cpio php53-5.3.3-22.el5_10.x86_64.rpm | cpio -idmv
```

#### Copy the files from the RPM package to its relevant place on the server

```
# cp php.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf
# cp libphp5.so /usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
... etc
```

No `httpd` installed!

Answer (score 2):

With the edit it's more clear what you want.
You already have httpd installed but not via RPMs.

In that case you can do it the way you did it by extracting the RPM.
Or by downloading the rpm and installing it via `rpm -i --nodeps php53....`.
In any case this won't be very nice.

If you install the RPM then upgrading the box won't be nice and might break it.
If you manually extract the shared object and place it there, you won't notice if there is an update with the standard CentOS tools.

Comment: I need to run php cgi/serve php web pages so I guess php-cli alone won't be enough.

Comment: It's really hard to say if we don't know what you are really trying to do. Maybe `php-fpm` is what you are looking for.

Comment: PHP 5.3 is available for CentOS/RHEL 5.10 without the need to use a 3rd party repo. As this is a production server, I'd like to limit the use of 3rd party repositories as much and as long as I can.

Comment: Yes, I also just noticed this (since CentOS 5.6 it seems). Anyway, with a self compiled Apache you may always need to manually copy files around. Alternative to your way would be to install the php53 package with `--nodeps` option. *Maybe*...